# How to display/append a file's path (or any text) into an edit box? (C++ Win32 API)

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, win32gui

In one of the programs I am working on (using only Win32 API), I am trying to use an open file dialog to select a file whose path will then appear in an edit box or a list box in the program. I have the open file dialog working (using OpenFileName), but I am not sure how I can display the selected file's path into the edit box.

I tried using the SendMessage function to do this but came up with nothing.

Here is the code I am using for the open file dialog (and where I would send the path to the edit box):

```
   int OpenDialog(HWND hWnd)
    {
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    TCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH];
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("txt Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0");
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
     {
       // the function to send the path name to the edit box would be here
     }
    }
```

Here is the code I used for the edit box:

```
    CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE, 
    20, 20, 380, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Is there a function or technique on how I can do this? Is there a certain way I need to code the edit box so this is possible? (Example code would be appreciated :))

(I am using CodeBlocks 13.12 on Windows 8)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is win32 API a necessary thing for you to use or learn ? I would say, don't let yourself simply try to use this system just because it seems like "oh, so that's the way". because it is not. in modern days (post 1999 let's say), Win32 API (and MFC even more) is getting stowed in the cellars for the better good of humanity, to the profit of Qt, Gtk and a myriad of others. Also doing interfaces is great, but its much better in C#, I suggest you try C#, and use C++ for windowless code.

Comment: @v.oddou 9% of all Windows developers are still writing native Windows applications (Windows API, MFC, WTL). Those 9% still generate the majority of revenue. Knowing the Windows API is neither arcane nor useless knowledge. It is in widespread use, and even if you find yourself writing Qt code, knowing the Windows API will make you a better developer.

Comment: @IInspectable: that's an absolutely laudable piece of comment indeed you make. And I won't say the contrary. But my first comment still remains true nonetheless. Now about myself, I have never coded in Qt, I only did a bit of Gtk, and I am using Devexpress at work. When I was young I also went through the same thing than sg185 and it took me years to truely grasp the full depth of what I was doing, maybe you get a better engineer from that; but certainly "because corporations are doing that" is a super wrong excuse to rot into this area. Instead the industry needs fresh blood that will...

Comment: ...be proactive and have incentive to move big and old corporations into cheaper technologies, with better software engineering development cycles, and more power and security. Consider that simply using the native Win32 controls expose your application GUI content to all other processes of the same permission level; its completely public. You can iterate window, iterate controls and retreive text box contents from another process. this is a crazy security flaw, chrome for example uses their own widgets to avoid that flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to hold the handle to the edit box so that you can reuse it later. You will need to make the handle accessible from the function where you are going to call SetWindowText on the edit box. So may be HWND can be a member variable of the class or a global variable. What ever you design is.

```
HWND hEditBox = CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE, 
    20, 20, 380, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Call SetWindowText after GetOpenFileName.

```
 if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
 {
    SetWindowText(hEditBox, ofn.lpstrFile);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks to both Ben and @goths for answering. The SetWindowText function was exactly what I needed! The program is now running smoothly with both the saved handle and SetWindowText.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- pass a dialog item ID to `CreateWindow` and use `SetDlgItemText`

  or
- save the `HWND` returned from `CreateWindow` and use `SetWindowText`

Comment: How exactly would I code that? (I checked MSDN and didn't find it very useful)

Comment: [`SetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only needs two parameters.  I've provided a hint where to get the HWND.  The string you already have, `szFile`.